# How to change selected tab icon color in native base Tabs?

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

This is a snippet of react-native. I need to change the selected tabs icon color to tabBar underline color. How to do it? I am trying code a tab bar like on the twitter android app.

```js
const TabBar = () => {
    return (
        <Tabs tabBarUnderlineStyle={styles.tabBarUnderline}>
            <Tab 
            heading={<TabHeading style={styles.tabHeading}>
            <Icon name="home" size={30} color="#B0BEC5" />
            </TabHeading>}
            >
                <Tab1 />
            </Tab>
            <Tab 
            heading={<TabHeading style={styles.tabHeading} ><Icon name="search" size={30} color="#B0BEC5" /></TabHeading>}
            
            >
                <Tab1 />
            </Tab>
            <Tab 
            heading={<TabHeading style={styles.tabHeading}><Icon name="notifications" size={30} color="#B0BEC5" /></TabHeading>}
            >
                <Tab1 />
            </Tab>
            <Tab 
            heading={<TabHeading style={styles.tabHeading}><Icon name="email" size={30} color="#B0BEC5" /></TabHeading>}
            >
                <Tab1 />
            </Tab>
        </Tabs>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    tabHeading: {
        backgroundColor: 'white',
    },
    tabBarUnderline: {
        backgroundColor: '#29B6F6',
        height: 3
    }
});

export default TabBar;
```

Comment: did'nt try customizing theme?

Comment: Is there any property to set icon color by tab selection?

Comment: I suggest you to go through `theme/variables`
You will find solution

Comment: any update on same or any alternative for this  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get various color icon from this website.
https://iconmonstr.com/

I have no idea how to change color of your icon.
Because your icon came from React Native Vector Icons.

in React Native Vector Icons wiki. 
below is read.
https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-iconsIcon Component
You can either use one of the bundled icons above or roll your own custom font.

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
const myIcon = (<Icon name="rocket" size={30} color="#900" />)
```

it may work well.

Comment: how to change the color property of the icon by tab selection?

Comment: I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to do something like that

```
 class TabIcon extends Component {

  render() {

    var color = this.props.focused ? '#5C6BC0' : '#E4E3E3';

    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'column', alignItems:'center', alignSelf:'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
       <View>
         <Icon name={this.props.title} size={30} color={color}  />}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


class App extends Component {
    render () {
      return (
        <Router>
        <Scene hideNavBar key="tabbar" type="reset" duration={1} initial={true}>
          <Scene key='main' showLabel={false} tabs={true} activeTintColor="#FF5722" titleStyle={styles.title} tabBarStyle={styles.tabBar} default="tab1">
            <Scene 
              key='tab1'
              title='search1'
              component={home}
              icon={TabIcon} 
              navBar={elementsHeader}
              />
            <Scene 
              key='tab2'
              component={home}
              icon={TabIcon} 
              title='power-sleep'
              navBar={elementsHeader}
              />
            <Scene 
              key='tab3'
              title='book'
              component={home}
              icon={TabIcon} 
              navBar={elementsHeader}
              />
            <Scene 
              key='tab4'
              title='setting'
              component={home}
              icon={TabIcon} 
              navBar={elementsHeader}
              />
          </Scene>
        </Scene>
        </Router>
        )
    }
}
```

reference => https://gist.github.com/rturk/858c1afaee170a3a141adc7da652883e