# Icon color not changing in bottom tab navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Active tint color is not working in react native bottom tab navigator. color of name does change when focused but icon color is not changing.
here is my navigator

```
<Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({route}) => ({
        tabBarIcon: ({focused, tintColor, size}) => {
          let iconName;

          if (route.name === 'Home') {
            iconName = focused
              ? 'chatbubble-ellipses-sharp'
              : 'chatbubble-ellipses-outline';
          } else if (route.name === 'Setting') {
            iconName = focused ? 'settings-sharp' : 'settings-outline';
          }

          // You can return any component that you like here!
          return (
            <Icon
              name={iconName}
              size={size}
              color={tintColor}
              type={'Ionicons'}
            />
          );
        },
      })}
      tabBarOptions={{
        activeTintColor: 'tomato',
        inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
      }}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Setting" component={Setting} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

even if i type color manually like `<Icon name={iconName} size={size} color={'red'} type={'Ionicons'} />` this it does not work.
any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using 'tintcolor'

but as per [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbaricon) it should be color

Change it like below and it should be done at screen level not at navigator level.

```
  <Tab.Screen
    name="Notifications"
    component={Notifications}
    options={{
      tabBarLabel: 'Updates',
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused,color, size }) => {
        const icon=focused?"bell":"home";
        return (
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name={icon} color={color} size={size} />
      )
      },
    }}
  />
```

And you can simply pass the colors you need like this

```
 tabBarOptions={{
    activeTintColor: 'red',
    inactiveTintColor: 'green',
  }}>
```

You can check out the sample snack here (You will have to change the icon to the ones you use)
[https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/createbottomtabnavigator-|-react-navigation](https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/createbottomtabnavigator-%7C-react-navigation)

And for the color of the icon in native base
use the option like below answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48062357/1435722

Comment: @AqsaMaan does the color have a value ?

Comment: even if i type color manually it doesnot work

Comment: where are you getting this Icon component from? whats the library

Comment: react native vector icons using native base

Comment: `<Icon name={iconName} size={size} color={'red'} type={'Ionicons'} />` evn if i type like this it does not work

Comment: it should work with color, can you try my updated answer?

Comment: u just removed `focused ` variable which gives error. other than that code is same

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@guruparan/createbottomtabnavigator-|-react-navigation

Comment: there is no parameter called focussed, let me fix this wait

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229765/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-aqsa-maan).

Answer (score 9):

In react navigation 6, these options are now screen options.

**Before (v5)**

```
<Tab.Navigator
  tabBarOptions={{
    inactiveTintColor: 'green',
    activeTintColor: 'red',
    style: {
      position: 'absolute',
      borderTopColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)',
    },
  }}
>
```

**After (v6)**

```
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'green',
    tabBarActiveTintColor: 'red',
    tabBarStyle: {
      position: 'absolute',
      borderTopColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)',
    },
  }}
>
```

Then on your icon you can do the following:

```
  <BottomTab.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={HomeScreen}
    options={({ navigation }) => ({
      title: "Home",
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color }) => (
        <Feather name="home" size={24} color={focused ? "red" : "green"} />
      ),
    })}
  />
```

View official docs with the documented changes here: https://reactnavigation.org/blog/2021/08/14/react-navigation-6.0/

Answer (score 0):

add tabBarActiveTintColor on the screenOptions
tabBarActiveTintColor: 'tomato' :

```
<Tab.Navigator
  screenOptions={({route}) => ({
    tabBarIcon: ({focused, tintColor, size}) => {
      let iconName;

      if (route.name === 'Home') {
        iconName = focused
          ? 'chatbubble-ellipses-sharp'
          : 'chatbubble-ellipses-outline';
      } else if (route.name === 'Setting') {
        iconName = focused ? 'settings-sharp' : 'settings-outline';
      }

      // You can return any component that you like here!
      return (
        <Icon
          name={iconName}
          size={size}
          color={tintColor}
          type={'Ionicons'}
        />
      );
    },
  })}
  tabBarOptions={{
    activeTintColor: 'tomato',
    inactiveTintColor: 'gray',enter code here
   tabBarActiveTintColor: 'tomato',
  }}>
  <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
  <Tab.Screen name="Setting" component={Setting} />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

);
}